# Return array key by value given (month given to return a date)

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP multidimensional array with a key and the array under has dates.

```
Array (
    [123] => Array
    (
       [one] => 2016-01-22 10:32:15
       [two] => 2016-02-21 14:24:15
       [three] => 2016-02-12 11:00:15
    )

    [553] => Array
    (
       [one] => 2016-03-22 10:32:15
       [two] => 2016-02-21 14:24:15
       [three] => 2016-08-12 11:00:15
    )

)
```

I need to get the key by month given. Example:

```
$value = '2016-02';

return 123 -> 2
return 552 -> 1
```

How would be the best approach to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: if  $value = '2016-02';  then output will be :-  123 ->two  and 123 ->three  and  552 ->two?  don't you think this will be output? cross-check once

Comment: @Anant yes right, I will use these values to count. At the end I just need to count the main keys that has the date in the month given.

Comment: just use a foreach and an if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below in simple way:-

```
<?php

$array = Array (
    '123' => Array
    (
       'one' => '2016-01-22 10:32:15',
       'two' => '2016-02-21 14:24:15',
       'three' => '2016-02-12 11:00:15'
    ),
    '553' => Array
    (
       'one' => '2016-03-22 10:32:15',
       'two' => '2016-02-21 14:24:15',
       'three' => '2016-08-12 11:00:15'
    )
);

$value = '2016-02';
$final_data = array();
foreach ($array as $key=> $arr){
  foreach($arr as $key1=>$val){
    if(strpos($val,$value)!==false){
       $final_data[$key][]=$key1;
    }
  }
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_data);
```

output:-https://eval.in/627935

Or this one is also useful:-

https://eval.in/627936

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply as below. I change code a little bit.

```
<?php
$date = Array (
123 => Array
(
   "2016-01-22 10:32:15",
   "2016-02-21 14:24:15",
   "2016-02-12 11:00:15"
),
553 => Array
(
   "2016-03-22 10:32:15",
   "2016-02-21 14:24:15",
   "2016-08-12 11:00:15"
)
);
$givenDate = "2016-02";
$givenMonth = explode("-",$givenDate)[1];

foreach ($date as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $k => $v){
        $d = explode(" ", $v);
        $d = explode("-", $d[0]);
        if($d[1] ==$givenMonth ){
            echo $key."=>".$k."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```